# Batch File - Find string and write filename to another file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, dos

i have 100 text files, and i need to find a string in all the 100 text files and if the string found in any of the file then i want to write that filename in a log, and i have many strings to be found in a separate text file, kindly provide a batch code to achieve this. strings are in a text file like below example,

my_strings.txt

test1

test2

test3

please help to achieve the above using a batch file.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read the [guide to asking a good question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) and show [what you have tried](http://whatyouhavetried.com).

Answer (score 0):

Here a few points to get you started to solving this problem yourself.

#### Searching Files and Printing File names see `Findstr`

Type `findstr /?` and enter at a command line.
Pay special attention to the `/M` option flag.

[`SS64`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)  [`Technet`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490907.aspx)

#### Capturing Output see `>>` Redirection

[`Rob`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php)